# Interfacing my MATLAB R2013a with Arduino

Tags: matlab, interfacing

I installed the MATLAB support package for arduino in my MATLAB r2013a today.
Now I plugged on my Arduino in my usb port.

And ran the command:

```
>> a = arduino()

>> Error: Undefined function or variable 'arduino'.
```

When I get:

```
>> a = arduino('COM18')

>> Undefined function 'arduino' for input arguments of type 'char'.
```

I have checked that this package has been installed.

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks very much

Anupam.

Comment: The pckage is not installed or the function is not called like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These won't work because MATLAB 2013a doesn't have these code (`arduino()`) in its library, to interface you need to upgrade MATLAB 2013a to MATLAB 2015a for interfacing.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't installed the package yet. Type " install_arduino"
"contents"
"arduino"

To install. Then you can type a= arduino('RELEVENT COM PORT')

This worked for me. Good luck.